# how to split string contains numbers in java?

Tags: java, regex, string, split

I have String like this: "LODIXAL COMP 15"

How can i split it to "LODIXAL COMP" and "15" ?

```
String a = "LODIXAL COMP 15";

String[] result = {"LODIXAL COMP" , "15"}
```

Comment: Please read [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/)

Comment: What's the exact criterion for the location of the split? Can the first returned string ever contain digits?

Comment: answerering on @aix's question will help create good answer to you. What you want to get for: AAA BBB 2 3 CCC 4? [AAA BBB, 2, 3, CCC, 4]?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use this [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) based regex:

```
a.split(" (?=\\d+)");
```

**TESTING:**

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a.split(" (?=\\d+)")));
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
[LODIXAL COMP, 15]
```

Comment: what with String a = "LODIXAL 12 3 COMP 15"; Output: [LODIXAL, 12, 3 COMP, 15]

Comment: @smas Yes this regex will not work with your string, you will need `a.split(" (?=\\d+$)")` for that. I can edit the answer but we don't know if OP can have string like that in his/her code.

Comment: there is other situation like this: String a = "ACEDICON COMP 1 X 5 MG" and it should be splits to "ACEDICON COMP 1"  and "X 5 MG".
How can i do it?

Comment: That can also be potentially done but IMHO that is very different problem than your original question. Why not ask a new question with that string and all of their variants. You will get much better answers that way.

Comment: For eg: you can use `a.split(" (?=X\\s*\\d+)");` for your string `"ACEDICON COMP 1 X 5 MG"`

Comment: thanks for your  comment.sure i will do it for my new Q in the feuture. to complete this subject, i should check out if my text( ACEDICON COMP 1 X 5 MG ) contains " X ". both side of X is whitespace.

Comment: If both side of X is whitespace then my suggestion in my last comment i.e. `a.split(" (?=X\\s*\\d+)");` should work.